# ValueError: Long orders require: SL < LIMIT < TP

Tags: python-3.x, bots, trading, mql5, expert-advisor

[this error msg when i run my code

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dkL9.jpg)

I am writing code for a bot in python but when i run it i got the ValueError msg. This is limiting me to increase take profit which I don't need. I want to put a lesser value for take profit but it is not allowing me. could anyone please help me solve this issue. here is the code which i am writing:

```
def support_trade_level(self, support, resistance, lower_support): 
    if self.close <= support + self.buy_point1 and self.close >= support - self.buy_point2:
        self.buy(sl= support - self.slo_buy_point, tp= resistance - self.tp_buy_point)
```

I know that if i increase take profit value then problem will get solve but that is a big issue for me I need to solve it without increasing take profit value.

Also could anyone help me to understand that when I am putting TP value at the time of position opening then why it consider LIMIT?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)